# iTextSharp XMLWorker Not Reading <link> CSS tags

Tags: c#, css, itext

So I have been racking my brain on this one.  Here is the following code:

```
string content = ConvertHTMLToXHTML(content); //This is something I wrote
var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);                
doc.Open();

ICSSResolver cssResolver = null;
cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCss(@"code { padding: 2px 4px; }", "utf-8", true);

//****This is the key line******
cssResolver.AddCssFile(@"<the css file>", true);

var hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider()));
hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors); // inject the tagProcessors
hpc.SetLinkProvider(new LinkProvider(currentWorkingDirectory));

var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer));

var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
var xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, Encoding.UTF8);

//Ok, now we can finally parse all this
using (var srHtml = new StringReader(content)) {
    xmlParser.Parse(srHtml);
}

doc.Close();
```

Notice the line where I wrote "This is the key line".  That is what I used for debugging purposes.

So, in the content, I have valid `<link href='[valid address]' rel="stylesheet" />` that is set in the `<head>` tags.  Pre-processing style, I made sure that the content was parsed to fully resolved href's using my method ConvertHTMLtoXHTML (it uses HTMLAgilityPack and I verified the content had fully resolved URLs).  Example fully resolved url is like `http://localhost/foo/bar.css`

However, the content does not render with the CSS.  Thus, I went to AddCssFile (see this is the keyline) and tried to add the file there via a URI path (this is all on my system, so I am using 'http://localhost/foo/bar/blah.css').  This threw an exception as it could not locate the file (exception was `System.IO.IOException: retrieve.file.from.nothing`).

I *then* went to add the file as it is on my file system via AddCssFile (ex: D:\foo\bar\blah.css), and thus it worked!!

My question is if there is a way to have the XMLWorker read the link tags (if I have them fully resolved) as opposed to me having to find all link tags, translate them over to where they are located on my disk, and add them via CSSResolver?

Additional Information:

- ASP.Net MVC 4
- iTextSharp 5.5.8
- iTextSharp.xmlworker 5.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identified a solution - had to dig through the source code of iTextSharp to figure out what was going on since I was using the compiled DLLs and the exception messages were not being completely helpful.

This is a 2 part-er by the way

**Authentication was required when getting in getting CSS**

My website only allowed authenticated users to use the website. Thus, when iTextSharp was making a `WebRequest` in `FileRetrieveImpl`, it was making a simple unauthenticated GET request. The request then failed with a 401 - Unauthorized which in turn threw a `retrieve.file.from.nothing` exception from iTextSharp.

In order to fix this, I needed to use the following code

```
WebRequest w = WebRequest.Create(url);
w.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
w.PreAuthenticate = true;
w.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

before the request was made. Thus, I needed to override the `FileRetrieve` on the `ICSSResolver` resolver I was using.  I decided I needed the current implementation of [`FileRetrieveImpl`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/net/FileRetrieveImpl.cs) while overriding the method `ProcessFromHref` which was causing my grief.

Thus, I wrote the following which I copied and pasted the items I needed from [`FileRetrieveImpl`](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/net/FileRetrieveImpl.cs).

```
private class CustomFileRetriever : FileRetrieveImpl {
    private static ILogger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.GetLogger(typeof(FileRetrieveImpl));
    private IList<string> rootdirs;
    private IList<string> urls;

    public CustomFileRetriever() {
        rootdirs = new List<string>();
        urls = new List<string>();
    }

    private Uri DetectWithRootUrls(string href) {
        foreach (string root in urls) {
            try {
                return new Uri(root + href);
            } catch (UriFormatException) {
            }
        }
        throw new UriFormatException();
    }

    public override void ProcessFromHref(string href, IReadingProcessor processor) {
        if (LOGGER.IsLogging(Level.DEBUG)) {
            LOGGER.Debug(string.Format(LocaleMessages.GetInstance().GetMessage("retrieve.file.from"), href));
        }
        Uri url = null;
        bool isfile = false;
        string f = href;
        try {
            url = new Uri(href);
        } catch (UriFormatException) {
            try {
                url = DetectWithRootUrls(href);
            } catch (UriFormatException) {
                // its probably a file, try to detect it.
                isfile = true;
                if (!(File.Exists(href))) {
                    isfile = false;
                    foreach (string root in rootdirs) {
                        f = Path.Combine(root, href);
                        if (File.Exists(f)) {
                            isfile = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Stream inp = null;

        if (null != url) {

            //***********************
            //Begin changed part
            //***********************
            WebRequest w = WebRequest.Create(url);
            w.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            w.PreAuthenticate = true;
            w.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //***********************
            //End changed part
            //***********************

            try {
                inp = w.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            } catch (WebException) {
                throw new IOException(LocaleMessages.GetInstance().GetMessage("retrieve.file.from.nothing"));
            }
        } else if (isfile) {
            inp = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        } else {
            throw new IOException(LocaleMessages.GetInstance().GetMessage("retrieve.file.from.nothing"));
        }
        Read(processor, inp);
    }

    private void Read(IReadingProcessor processor, Stream inp) {
        try {
            int inbit = -1;
            while ((inbit = inp.ReadByte()) != -1) {
                processor.Process(inbit);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != inp) {
                    inp.Close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeWorkerException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I simply overrode the default file retriever

```
ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.FileRetrieve = new CustomFileRetriever();
```

This addressed the issue of me calling calling `AddCssFile` and getting `retrieve.file.from.nothing`. However, I would not just like to call AddCssFile, I would like to have iTextSharp identify the links. Thus, this lead me to the next part.

**Link Tags in HTML Source Require Specific Attributes**

In my problem statement, I wrote about how it was not picking up `<link href='[valid address]' rel="stylesheet" />`.  This was because it was missing the attribute tag `type="text/css"`.  Thus, I should have had `<link href='[valid address]' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

I identified this by reading through the source code (see [Link](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/html/head/Link.cs)).  When processing XHTML tags, it looks to see that the tag is completely there and fully resolved.